# Using a SQL Server database file

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm learning basic c# using visual studio 2010 and I'm creating an application which uses a SQL server database. 
The application will allow a user to enter text into a rich text box, press a button, and then show "stored" words in text box 2. These stored words are only words that being with *. 
I have my database file but I can't figure out how to do the code for it. So far I have,

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\datafile.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM bbc", con);
SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
while (sdr.Read())
{
    this.txtbox2.Text.Add(sdr[""]);
}
```

this is under my button handler.

I have my data file set up so it's just the case of really how to set it to get data from text box 1 and show it in text box 2

Comment: Note that you're connecting to the master database in your connection string. You should either connect to the database that contains your bbc table or put the full schema information in your SQL query.

Comment: yeah sorry, I pasted from my older code, please see the updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
//SQL Connection stuff here
con.Open();
String queryStr = "SELECT name FROM bbc WHERE name LIKE '*%'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(queryStr, con);
SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();

while(sdr.Read())
{
   this.textbox2.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```

It's much more simple and usually more efficient to let SQL limit your query results.

Comment: I seem the get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\datafile.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (sdr.Read())
{
    string value = sdr["name"].ToString();
    if(value.Contains("*"))
        builder.Append(value );
}

this.txtbox2.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to show the words beginning with '*' - Then you can limit your database query to only return them:

```
SELECT name FROM bbc where name like '*%'
```

The '%' character is a wildcard - meaning only return results starting with '*' and ending with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following:

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    string value = sdr["name"].ToString();
    if(value.StartsWith("*"))
        txtbox2.Text += value;
}
```

A couple points:

- Put a using around the SqlConnection so it closes it automatically for you.
- I noticed you are trying to connect to the Master database. Why?
- Dave makes a good point about using the wild card `%` to limit the results.